# Font for Words in a sentence needs to be italic using vb

Tags: vb.net

I need to display the following content in the body of my email. Words "orders" and 
"dispatch" need to be in italic.

code in VB:

```
tlBody = tlBody.Replace("DBCOLUMN1", ds.Tables(1).Rows(1)(0).ToString)
tlBody = tlBody.Replace(“001value”, “ All ““orders” “must be within the 
 “”dispatch”” date.”)
```

DBCOLUMN1 is grabbed from database table which has "Action" as value

Desired output

Action:

All “orders” must be within the “dispatch” date.

Current output

Action:

All “orders” must be within the “dispatch” date.

Comment: Is tlBody a string?

Comment: @djv   Yes it is declared as   Dim tlBody As String = String.Empty

Comment: And that's assigned to `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage.Body`, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Using [System.Net.Mail.MailMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage(v=vs.110).aspx) class to send your email, you can format the body as Html

```
MailMessage.IsBodyHtml = True
```

Then, the body can contain italic tags

```
tlBody = tlBody.Replace("001value", " All <i>orders</i> must be within the <i>dispatch</i> date.")
```

Here's a complete example with bold tags (works the same way): http://www.systemnetmail.com/faq/3.1.2.aspx